# How to use a fixed port with the webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT?

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing

I am working on an Integration Test, and I want the server to launch on the same port every time. I have set the value of webEnvironment to DEFINED_PORT in the @SpringBootTest annotation. However, a random port is still being accessed. How to fix the port value?

```
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = AdsApplication.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@TestExecutionListeners(
        listeners = {
            SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
            ServletTestExecutionListener.class,
            DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class
        })
@RunWith(RunIfRunnerExtended.class)
@RunIfExtended(LocalCheck.class)
public class AutoSpecUpdateIntegrationTest {

//    @LocalServerPort 
    private int randomServerPort = 63547;

    @Test
    public void autoSpecUpdate() throws IOException {
  

        String url = "http://localhost:" + randomServerPort + "/" + version + "/api-docs";


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with webEnvironment you need to define property `server.port`. It may fail after first test case and throw error `Port 8090 is already in use`. To avoid that you need to add `@DirtiesContext` annotation.

```
@SpringBootTest(
  webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT,
  properties = {
    "server.port=8090"
  })
@DirtiesContext
```

Now you can use @LocalServerPort to get port.